# eval(formula) not working inside boxplot in R

Tags: r, function, eval, boxplot

I am trying to create a function which will make a boxplot with one numeric variable vs. one specified other variable. Like this:

```
plot_box <- function(x){
 formula <- paste("logerror~",x, sep="")
 boxplot(eval(formula), data = data)
}
```

But this results in the following error:`Error in x[floor(d)] + x[ceiling(d)] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Why doesn't eval work inside boxplot, while it works inside other functions (e.g. lm())?

Reproducible example:

```
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(y = rnorm(30), x = sample(seq(1,5), 30, replace =T))
formula <- "y~x"
boxplot(eval(formula), data = data)
```

> Error in x[floor(d)] + x[ceiling(d)] :    non-numeric argument to
>   binary operator

```
boxplot(y~x, data = data)
lm(eval(formula), data = data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for your problem:

```
set.seed(1)
dts <- data.frame(y = rnorm(30), x = sample(seq(1,5), 30, replace =T))

plot_box <- function(x, data) {
 formula <- paste("y~",x, sep="")
 boxplot(eval(parse(text=formula)), data = data)
}
plot_box("x", dts)

formula <- "y~x"
boxplot(eval(parse(text=formula)), data = dts)
```

[image]